# 401 unauthorized urban airship error android

Tags: android, httpclient, urbanairship.com

My code is:

```
 String encodedData = Base64.encodeBytes("YxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxA".getBytes());

 HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
               HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
               HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
               HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

               HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/airmail/send/broadcast/");
              //request.setHeader(header)
               request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedData)
```

Am using application master secret as per the document suggested here:

http://urbanairship.com/docs/richpush.html?highlight=broadcast

but am getting 401 unauthorized error.

How to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 401 error means you aren't properly authenticated. See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error

Are you sure you are providing your credentials properly?

Comment: Yes am the master secret is to be passed and i checked its correct but is this way of authenticating..

Comment: Ugh, it's 2016 and I have this problem now. No one seems to have answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664399/how-come-i-keep-getting-a-request-failed-with-response-code-401-when-trying-to