# How come I keep getting a "Request failed with response code 401" when trying to push via Urban Airship?

Tags: parse-platform, urbanairship.com

I have double, triple, and quadruple checked that I have the right master key that I'm passing. My parameters are taking directly from the UA website also so it can't be that. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here???

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendPush", function(request, response) {

  var Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer;

  var parameters = {
    "audience" : "all",
     "device_types" : "all",
     "notification" : {
         "alert" : "Hello from Urban Airship."
     }
  };

  var params = JSON.stringify(parameters);

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: "https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        "Authorization" : 'Basic ' + new Buffer('MASTER_KEY').toString('base64'),
        "Accept" : "application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;"
    },
    body: params,
    success: function(httpResponse) {
        response.error(httpResponse);
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) {
      response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
    }
  });

});
```

I've also tried adding in APP_SECRET:

```
"Authorization" : 'Basic ' + new Buffer('APP_SECRET':'MASTER_KEY').toString('base64'),
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your code sample if you are including the app key in your request. API requests to Urban Airship use HTTP basic authentication. The username portion is the application key and the password portion in this case is the master secret. The application secret is restricted to lower-security APIs and is for use in the distributed application. The master secret is needed for sending messages and other server API requests.

Urban Airship provides a guide for [troubleshooting common API issues](https://support.urbanairship.com/entries/70139918-API-Troubleshooting-Guide).

Comment: Yes, I've read and re-read all the troubleshooting solutions and have tried all the solutions and many many other variations and combinations for the "Authorization" field but nothing seems to work. I can push from the UA website easily enough but this Parse server-side code can't seem to get the authorization right. I'm at a dead-end here and re-thinking my approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried to figure it out by Network diagnosing tools for more than two days. Because after debugging I checked that I send the right credentials to UA.  After all I called the UA and ask them to check the Credentials (in my case  was appKey and appToken for streaming with java-connect API) if they are still valid. They checked and approved the validation but just in case sent me a new credentials. And I could connect with the new credentials!
It is for sure a bug by UA because I tested the whole time by another test application, which was a Desktop java application and I could connect to the server (with the same appKey and appToken) and get the events, but I got 401 error in my main Application, which was a Web Application running on TomCat 8.0 . It means It worked in a same time in with the same credential for one application and did not work for another application.